# Pesquisa por voz no genexus device

Tags: genexus

Estou procurando uma solução em genexus dovece, que realize a busca de produtos por voz, mesmo recurso da API do google, alguém tem alguma dica de como fazer ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

GeneXus não tem essa funcionalidade, mais voce pode desenvolver un "external object" para fazer isso.

Veja mais informação [aquí](http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/hwikibypageid?17880), de como criar um "external objet".

Voce vai precissar de uma API para converter a voz para texto.